# bibtex: author and editor inbook

Tags: bibtex

In the .bst file, the `inbook` function looks like this:

```
FUNCTION {inbook}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
        { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
     format.bvolume output
          format.chapter.pages "chapter and pages" output.check
      new.block
      format.number.series output
      new.sentence
      format.publisher.address output
    }
    {
      format.chapter.pages "chapter and pages" output.check
      new.block
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}
```

and produces a `can't use both editor and author fields` error. However, for `inproceedings` it's fine:

```
FUNCTION {inproceedings}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
      format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      format.pages output
      new.sentence
      publisher empty$
        { format.organization.address output }
        { organization "organization" bibinfo.check output
          format.publisher.address output
        }
      if$
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}
```

Does somebody know how to fix the `ìnbook` entry?

Comment: Which `.bst` file? 'Fix' here may be misleading: this is a deliberate decision to not allow the two fields.

Comment: I believe the `@inbook` entry type is meant for references to a chapter (or chapters) within a specific book, with all chapters authored (or edited) by the same author(s) (or editor(s)). The `@inproceedings` type is designed for more complicated entries, e.g., for parts of a Proceedings volume, where individual chapters have an author (or authors) and the entire volume has a separate editor (or editors).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The idea is that an `inbook` entry refers to a `book` entry, and therefore should not have an `editor`. So the following works without warning:

```
@inbook{inbook,
  author = {A. Inbook-Author},
  title = {The title of the inbook entry},
  pages = {1--5},
  year = 2013,
  crossref = "book",
  volume = 1,
}
@book{book,
  title = {A title of the book entry},
  year = 2013,
  editor = {E. Book-Editor},
  publisher = {Book Publishing Inc.},
}
```

This is also reflected by the fact that an `inbook` entry has no `booktitle` field, not even as an option. `BibTeX` does not enforce that every `inbook` has a `crossref` to a `book`, but I guess this is the only sensible way to use it. (A little less convincing is the fact that a `book` also can not have `author` and `editor`.)

What you are looking for is probably the `incollection` entry. This entry type even *requires* a `booktitle` field. Note also that there is no `collection` entry type, that would be the natural target of a cross-referencing `incollection` entry. An `incollection` entry can have both an `author`, and an `editor` field.

The `inproceedings` entry is just a variant of `incollection` where the `publisher` field is optional (and some more minor variations). So it should *not* be seen as an entry type that usually cross-reference to a `proceedings` entry.  The analogy breaks here, unfortunately. The `proceedings` type, however, is again quite similar to a book with optional `publisher`.

Note, however, that those rules are not infallible. When they were laid down a number of aspects of publishing were not addressed. So these helpful hints of BibTeX documentation always apply:

> The standard style’s thirteen entry types do reasonably well at
>   formatting most entries, but no scheme with just thirteen formats can
>   do everything perfectly. Thus, *you should feel free to be creative in
>   how you use these entry types* (but if you have to be too creative,
>   there's a good chance you're using the wrong entry type).
>
> *Don't take the ﬁeld names too seriously.* Sometimes, for instance, you
>   might have to include the publisher's address along with the
>   publisher's name in the publisher ﬁeld, rather than putting it in the
>   address ﬁeld. Or sometimes, difficult entries work best when you make
>   judicious use of the note ﬁeld.
>
> *Don't take the warning messages too seriously.* Sometimes, for
>   instance, the year appears in the title, as in The 1966 World Gnus
>   Almanac. In this case it's best to omit the year ﬁeld and to ignore
>   BibTEX’s warning message.

(Emphasis mine)

Comment: thank you! `incollection` is what I'm looking for! - apparently can't fully rely on the auto-generated bibtex ;)

Comment: It seems you could sensibly use `inbook` to cite an individual chapter without a `crossref` to a book? Maybe I am using it wrong though.

Answer (score 1):

This is all very well, but I work in the history of logic, and I come across a very large number of works with both authors and editors. These books are usually
critical editions of works by famous logicians. They are not collections. For example, the critical edition of Ockham's Summa Logicae has an author (William of Ockham) and three editors (Philotheus Boehner, Gideon Gal, and Steve Brown). See http://www.logicmuseum.com/wiki/Summa_Logicae_(Ockham). Now I am aware that it is possible to get around this by using INCOLLECTION, but most of these works are not collections: they are editions of books. (Also, while I'm on this, BibTeX does not seem to have a distinction between a book and an edition of a book: maybe it should do this, too). Why is this important? Well, one might want to do some data harvesting from BibTeX files to some other bibliographic database, and this practice makes it impossible. BibTeX needs to be mended.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please ask a new question?

Comment: Will do. Thanks

Comment: @GrahamWhite did you?