# Bibliography warning messages for entries of type @inbook

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I have issues with these bibliography entries but don't know how to fix them (highlighted in yellow):

[image]

```
 @InBook{Houseman2002,
  chapter   = {Model Systems for Studying Polyvalent Carbohydrate Binding Interactions},
  pages     = {1-44},
  title     = {Host-Guest Chemistry: Mimetic Approaches to Study Carbohydrate Recognition},
  publisher = {Springer Berlin Heidelberg},
  year      = {2002},
  author    = {Houseman, B T and Mrksich, M},
  editor    = {Soledad Penad{\'e}s},
  volume    = {218},
}


@Article{Steinmeyer2017,
  author   = {Steinmeyer, Jeannine and R\"{o}nicke, Franziska and Schepers, Ute and Wagenknecht, Hans-Achim },
  title    = {Synthesis of Wavelength-Shifting Fluorescent DNA and RNA with Two Photostable Cyanine-Styryl Dyes as the Base Surrogate Pair},
  journal  = {ChemistryOpen},
  year     = {2017},
  issn     = {2191-1363},
  doi      = {10.1002/open.201700059},
  keywords = {chromophores, energy transfer, fluorescence, imaging, oligonucleotides},
  url      = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/open.201700059},
}

@InBook{Lindhorst2002,
  chapter   = {Artificial Multivalent Sugar Ligands to Understand and Manipulate Carbohydrate-Protein Interactions},
  pages     = {201-235},
  title     = {Host-Guest Chemistry: Mimetic Approaches to Study Carbohydrate Recognition},
  publisher = {Springer Berlin Heidelberg},
  year      = {2002},
  author    = {Lindhorst, Thisbe K},
  editor    = {Penad{\'e}s, Soledad},
  volume    = {218},
  address   = {Berlin, Heidelberg},
  isbn      = {978-3-540-45010-8},
  booktitle = {Host-Guest Chemistry: Mimetic Approaches to Study Carbohydrate Recognition},
  doi       = {10.1007/3-540-45010-6_7},
  url       = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/3-540-45010-6_7},
}

@InBook{Schwechheimer2016,
 author    = {Schwechheimer, Christian and Merkel, Marcus and Bohl{\"a}nder, Peggy R and Wagenknecht, Hans-Achim},
 chapter   = {Synthetic Wavelength-Shifting Fluorescent Probes of Nucleic Acids},
  pages     = {83-100},
  title     = {Modified Nucleic Acids},
  publisher = {Springer International Publishing},
  year      = {2016},
  editor    = {Nakatani Kazuhiko and Tor Yitzhak},
  volume    = {31},
  address   = {Cham},
  isbn      = {978-3-319-27111-8},
  booktitle = {Modified Nucleic Acids},
  doi       = {10.1007/978-3-319-27111-8_4},
  url       = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-27111-8_4},
}


@InBook{Flimbook,
  chapter   = {Fluorescence lifetime imaging techniques: Time-correlated single photon counting},
  pages     = {203-232},
  title     = {Fluorescence lifetime spectroscopy and imaging},
  publisher = {Taylor \& Francis Group},
  year      = {2015},
  author    = {Wolfgang Becker},
  editor    = {Marcu, Laura and French, Paul M W and Elson, Daniel S },
}
```

`

Comment: Could you post a full compilable code reproducing the problem?

Comment: I think it is a dupplicate of this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103425/bibtex-author-and-editor-inbook

Comment: @koleygr - It's not a duplicate! What's different about the new posting is that the problem is based on the inappropriate use of the entry typo `@inbook` -- the OP should be using `@incollection` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misusing the entry type `@inbook` for four of the entries you posted. You should be using the entry type `@incollection` instead.

Moreover, in all four of these entries, you should (a) change the field `title` to `booktitle` and (b) change the field `chapter` to `title`. The field `chapter`, if present, should contain a *number*, not the *title* of the chapter.

With these changes in place, you'll notice that the entries with keys `Lindhorst2002` and `Schwechheimer2016` have two, identical `booktitle` fields -- get rid of the duplicate fields.

Here's how I would write the four entries:

```
@incollection{Flimbook,
  title        = "Fluorescence lifetime imaging techniques:
                  Time-correlated single photon counting",
  pages        = "203-232",
  booktitle    = "Fluorescence lifetime spectroscopy and
                  imaging",
  publisher    = "Taylor \& Francis Group",
  address      = "London",
  year         = "2015",
  author       = "Wolfgang Becker",
  editor       = "Marcu, Laura and French, Paul M. W. and Elson,
                  Daniel S. ",
}

@incollection{Houseman2002,
  title        = "Model Systems for Studying Polyvalent
                  Carbohydrate Binding Interactions",
  pages        = "1-44",
  booktitle    = "Host-Guest Chemistry: Mimetic Approaches to
                  Study Carbohydrate Recognition",
  publisher    = "Springer",
  address      = "Berlin \& Heidelberg",
  year         = "2002",
  author       = "Houseman, B. T. and Mrksich, M.",
  editor       = "Soledad Penad{\'e}s",
  volume       = "218",
}

@incollection{Lindhorst2002,
  title        = "Artificial Multivalent Sugar Ligands to
                  Understand and Manipulate
                  Carbohydrate-Protein Interactions",
  pages        = "201-235",
  booktitle    = "Host-Guest Chemistry: Mimetic Approaches to
                  Study Carbohydrate Recognition",
  publisher    = "Springer",
  address      = "Berlin \& Heidelberg",
  year         = "2002",
  author       = "Lindhorst, Thisbe K.",
  editor       = "Penad{\'e}s, Soledad",
  volume       = "218",
  isbn         = "978-3-540-45010-8",
  doi          = "10.1007/3-540-45010-6_7",
  url          = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/3-540-45010-6_7",
}

@incollection{Schwechheimer2016,
  author       = "Schwechheimer, Christian and Merkel, Marcus
                  and Bohl{\"a}nder, Peggy R and Wagenknecht,
                  Hans-Achim",
  title        = "Synthetic Wavelength-Shifting Fluorescent
                  Probes of Nucleic Acids",
  pages        = "83-100",
  publisher    = "Springer",
  address      = "Cham",
  year         = "2016",
  editor       = "Nakatani, Kazuhiko and Tor, Yitzhak",
  volume       = "31",
  isbn         = "978-3-319-27111-8",
  booktitle    = "Modified Nucleic Acids",
  doi          = "10.1007/978-3-319-27111-8_4",
  url          = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-27111-8_4",
}
```